# React native -- call phone number with extension

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to open phone number with extension.
Linking works with just phone number

Tried with few options

```
Linking.openURL('tel:XXXXXXXXX,XXX');

Linking.openURL('tel:'+ encodeURIComponent('XXXXXXXXX,XXX'));
```

Dialer only dials primary number and doesnt include extension

I could write a native code and expose the method, but that would be my last option

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I know it is late, but you can try this component: [react-native-communications](https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications).

It works well both on iOS and Android.

You have to import it in the file you need:

```
import Communications from 'react-native-communications';
```

and then use it as you need:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Communications.phonecall(phoneNumbers[0].number, true)}>
```

Comment: I just looked at this library's code, and all it does is call the very same Linking.openURL, so I don't know how this can be helpful on this case

Answer (score 19):

This is what i tried,

```
callNumber = (url) =>{
   Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
   if (!supported) {
    console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
   } else {
    return Linking.openURL(url);
   }
 }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
}
```

And the JSX,

```
<Text onPress={()=> this.callNumber(`tel:+91${user.number}`)}
       style = {[styles.value,{marginLeft : 5,textDecorationLine :'underline'}]}>{`+91 ${user.number}`}</Text>
</View>
```

Works fine for me.
You may find more on linking here,
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

Comment: It needs to be tested on a device. It might not work in simulator.

Comment: And replacing "tel" with "mailto" would launch email app. Yay!