# How to access to current call in Android

Tags: react-native

The primary use case is:
When a phone call occurs, I would want to do certain things inside my app after call end. I need this information about call - call length, caller phone number,type of call (in / out).

How I cat do it in RN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that there is no such API available for React-Native yet. Unless I'm wrong with my previous statement, you would have to write your own Native Modules for Android and iOS and bind them to your React Native project. Writing a native module is pretty simple, especially if you are familiar with the native language and APIs of each platform. Below are the links to the official docs.

1. [Native Modules for Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)
2. [Native Modules for iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074623/react-native-call-phone-number-with-extension/39941362#39941362